# Is this a criminal threat?

Tags: criminal-law

I am involved in a nasty domestic dispute with a family member.
This domestic dispute involves my knowledge of criminal activity by persons X, Y and Z. I reported this criminal activity to my local police department.

One of my family members is married to person X and became very upset when told that I had reported this information to the police. My family member sent me the following text message:

> You are messing with the wrong people. Person X is going to come after you bad. You have made a lot of people very angry. I would watch my back if I were you.

Is this remark a criminal threat against me?

Should I report it to the police?